# Digital picture processing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, sdk, pixel, image

I want to write application on iPhone which will:

- make some digital processing on video from iPhone camera (in real time)
- send some graphics through TV-Out

Could You tell me if this above is possible on iPhone 3G or 3GS? 
Can I have access to each pixel in video capturing via iPhone camera?

Comment: Please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889683/how-to-implemet-digital-picture-frame-in-ios-app if you can..

Answer (score 1):

There are private access points to do both live video recording and [TV out](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-app-video-out/). They are not well documented so you won't find much about them though and you wouldn't be able to submit anything that uses them to the app store. Real time video capture will probably eventually become a public part of the SDK but TV is probably less likely at this point.

Comment: Please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889683/how-to-implemet-digital-picture-frame-in-ios-app if you can..