# how to implemet Digital picture frame in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, uiimage, image-manipulation

I want to develop an application which shows photos like digital picture frame (One by one photo slides automatically and shows animation).

How to do it ? 
Is there any sdk available or I have to do it by my own logic ?
Please help me if anyone can suggest any reference link.

Comment: Please ask specific questions, if your are facing any difficulties. this is a community for helping each other difficulties. not a solution provider

Comment: I know, But I am unable to find any sdk or link regrading it. That's why I had asdked this question

Comment: Did you try Cocoapods?

Comment: No, I have not any idea.. If you can suggest me any link.. then please help me

Comment: U can try use scroll view to show the image by page...? set a timer to auto scroll with `setContentOffset`...But atleast give some idea or what u have achieved so ppl can understand more what u'r trying to do

Comment: I want to implement digital picture frame in my app in which animation done by changing images one by one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer but might help

You can install cocoa pods using `sudo gem install cocoapods`

then go to

> https://cocoapods.org/

and search for the components you need. 
most of the pods will have necessary info how to use it

You can also visit

> https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios

this will have a curated list of awesome pods

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I will prefer your link.